# htaccess - webapp in a subfolder doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a custom webapp in a root folder like `www.mypage.com` in a hosting, now i need to move it in a subfolder like `www.mypage.com/subfolder`.

This is my .httaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  Options -Indexes
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_]*)/?([a-zA-Z-_]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-_]*)?/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I understand that to make it works in a subfolder I need to modify the RewriteBase from `/` to `/subfolder` or `/subfolder/` but I can't make it works.

What im doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: Hi, it throws me an error 500, but for some strange reason y re-edited the htaccess locally and upload it and magically it works.